# Finding out the supported SSH compression of a session with libssh

Tags: c++, ssh, compression, libssh

Recently I've been dabbling with networking and specifically libssh.
I've been connecting to a server, and everything works pretty well but now I would like to find out some kind of way to discover what (if any) compression a server uses. I've tried the ssh_options_get() function with SSH_OPTIONS_COMPRESSION:

```
ssh_options_get(s_session, SSH_OPTIONS_COMPRESSION, comp);
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

The documentation doesn't say anything about recieving the compression level with any of these commands. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be very thankful!